# Calculating how much time has lapsed in % javascript

Tags: javascript, math, time

Good evening!

I just started messing around with JavaScript, and I am trying to do some calculations, but i am not sure how to do that.

So in my test project, I am grabbing string of EPG (ElectronicProgramGuide) of tv channel.
This string has start and end time of show + minutes how long show will be still on.

For example:

> NOW: [**21:00** - **22:45**] +**25** min Star Wars

So this string tells us that at moment Star Wars is on, it started at 21:00 and ends at 22:45, it also shows that there is 25 minutes until it ends.

For outcome I am trying to create a progress bar of show status of show length.

In HTML I only have 1 div, where I output `<meter>` after calculations are made:

```
<div id="epgMeter">
</div>
```

So here's what I have so far, I have extracted all needed values from string.
But as for further progress I am not sure how to do the math best.

```
var epgdata = "NOW: [15:00 - 16:00] +30 min Some Show";

//GET SHOW START AND END TIME
var startEnd = epgdata.split("[");
var startEnd = startEnd[1].split("]");
var stillToGo = startEnd[1].split(" min");
var startEnd = startEnd[0].split(" - ");

var stillToGo = stillToGo[0].replace('+', ''); //30
var showStart = startEnd[0]; //15:00
var showEnd = startEnd[1]; //16:00


//SOME MATH MAGIC SHOULD HAPPEN HERE SO THE OUTCOME WOULD BE 50% IN CURRENT CASE

var precentageOfshowLapsed = "50"; //JUST FOR TESTING

document.getElementById("epgMeter").innerHTML='<meter value="'+precentageOfshowLapsed+'" min="0" max="100"></meter>';
```

EDIT: We should not use current time, because timezones may differ.

Comment: Seems that you could simplify by using "substr" and inserting the hours and minutes directly into a date like so:  var showStart = new Date(); showStart.setHours( data.substr(6,2), data.substr(9,2), 0, 0 );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I would approach this:

```
function getMinutes(str){
    var arr = str.split(":");
    if(arr.length == 1) return Number(arr[0])
    return Number(arr[0])*60+Number(arr[1])
}

var epgdata = "NOW: [15:00 - 16:00] +30 min Some Show";

var start = getMinutes(epgdata.match(/\[([^ ]*)/)[1]) // regex group
var end = getMinutes(epgdata.match(/([^ ]*)\]/)[1])// regex group

var stillToGo = getMinutes(epgdata.match(/(\d*) min/)[1])// regex group

var percentage = (1-(stillToGo/(end - start)))*100 // formula for remaining percentage

console.log(percentage)
```

`end-start` gives us the minutes between the end and the start, which means the duration of the show in minutes. Then we do `StillToGo /(end-start)`, which gives us between 0 and 1, the percentage of the minutes stillToGo. As we want the run percentage instead of the remaining percentage, we do 1 - all that. Finally, multiply by 100 to have the percentage between 0 and 100

Comment: This is excelent approach, just 1 more question, what if stillToGo is more precise , for example 30.2 (note the point its not comma) instead of 30. Then precentage would be wrong.  Is it better to just take it out the .2 or can we round it somehow?

Comment: Well, what would 30.2 be? 30 minutes with 12 seconds?

Comment: Good question, propably yes (i dont generate epg, i parse it from webpage). Its not really so important to make it so precise, maybe its better to filter it out with string.split or in your case with regex.

Comment: In any case, to make the regex work you would need to change it to `epgdata.match(/\+(.*) min/)[1]` to consider the dot and then change `return Number(arr[0])` to `return Number(arr[0].split(".")[0])` to discard it

Answer (score 0):

using Date objects:

https://jsfiddle.net/deez2ho1/

this solution basically creates two Date objects, sets the hours and minutes, computes the difference in milliseconds, and then computes the percentage. But using regex from the start is probably a better solution to parse the time information in `epgdata`;

```
var epgdata = "NOW: [15:00 - 16:00] +30 min Some Show";

//GET SHOW START AND END TIME
var startEnd = epgdata.split("[");
var startEnd = startEnd[1].split("]");
var stillToGo = startEnd[1].split(" min");
var startEnd = startEnd[0].split(" - ");

var stillToGo = stillToGo[0].replace('+', ''); //30
var showStart = startEnd[0]; //15:00
var showEnd = startEnd[1]; //16:00



// using Date Objects
// create the Dates
var start = new Date();
var end = new Date();

// set hours and minutes
start.setHours(parseInt(startEnd[0].split(":")[0], 10));
start.setMinutes(parseInt(startEnd[0].split(":")[1], 10));
end.setHours(parseInt(startEnd[1].split(":")[0], 10));
end.setMinutes(parseInt(startEnd[1].split(":")[1], 10));

var overallMinutes = (end - start) / (1000 * 60);
var precentageOfshowLapsed = parseInt(stillToGo, 10) / overallMinutes; 

precentageOfshowLapsed *= 100;

document.getElementById("epgMeter").innerHTML = '<meter value="' + precentageOfshowLapsed + '" min="0" max="100"></meter>';
```